# Where can I find an online version of the Adhyatma Ramayana?

Tags: ramayana, translation-request, resource

I am looking for an accompanied translation in either Hindi or English. A translation done by an Indian author would be preferred.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Unabridged English translation by Rai Bahadur Lala Baij Nath:

   https://archive.org/details/TheAdhyatmaRamayana

   Link to [PDF](https://archive.org/download/TheAdhyatmaRamayana/The%20adhyatma%20ramayana_text.pdf)
2. Hindi translation by Munilal (with original Sanskrit verses):

   https://archive.org/details/AdhyatmaRamayana

   Link to [PDF](https://archive.org/download/AdhyatmaRamayana/GitaPress-AdhyatmaRamayan-Unabridged-Munilalsanskrit-hindi.pdf)
3. Abridged English translation by Srikrishna Prapnnachari: [indiadivine.org](http://www.indiadivine.org/content/files/file/21-adhyatma-ramayana-in-english-pdf/?do=download&csrfKey=32cd2d3182eab9691bf1440d6bc79d2e) (PDF)

Answer (score 4):

Also available is a scanned copy pdf file of Adhyatama Ramayan by Swami Tapasyananda of Ramkrishna Mission. 
Free download at http://estudantedavedanta.net/Adhyatma%20Ramayana_Tapasyananda.pdf

Answer (score 3):

An English version of the Adhyatma Ramayana is available on [e samskriti](http://esamskriti.com):

1. [Adhyatma Ramayana Volume 1](http://www.esamskriti.com/essays/ARamayan-Vol_1.pdf) (Bala Kandam & Ayodhya Kandam)
2. [Adhyatma Ramayana Volume 2](http://esamskriti.com/essays/pdf22.pdf) (Aranya Kandam, Kishkinda Kandam & Sundara Kandam)
3. [Adhyatma Ramayana Volume 3](http://esamskriti.com/essays/murti.pdf) (Yuddha Kandam)